# How to create a gradient sliver app bar in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

I just wanna create a sliver app bar like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UWNFgqkmlQa0B1pkCuB8BzvSr3ha9weL/view?usp=drivesdk) but I am stucked in.

What I tried so far is to create a sliver app bar and using a container in the flexible space with some gradient but it wasn't that nice compared to the link.

So please help me achieve it more accurately.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  bool _pinned = true;
  bool _snap = false;
  bool _floating = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            pinned: _pinned,
            snap: _snap,
            floating: _floating,
            expandedHeight: 160.0,
            flexibleSpace: const FlexibleSpaceBar(
              title: Text('SliverAppBar'),
              background: FlutterLogo(),
            ),
          ),
          const SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 20,
              child: Center(
                child: Text('Scroll to see SliverAppBar'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                  (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Container(
                  color: index.isOdd ? Colors.white : Colors.black12,
                  height: 100.0,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text('$index', textScaleFactor: 5),
                  ),
                );
              },
              childCount: 20,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: OverflowBar(
            overflowAlignment: OverflowBarAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  const Text('pinned'),
                  Switch(
                    onChanged: (bool val) {
                      setState(() {
                        _pinned = val;
                      });
                    },
                    value: _pinned,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  const Text('snap'),
                  Switch(
                    onChanged: (bool val) {
                      setState(() {
                        _snap = val;
                        _floating = _floating || _snap;
                      });
                    },
                    value: _snap,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  const Text('floating'),
                  Switch(
                    onChanged: (bool val) {
                      setState(() {
                        _floating = val;
                        _snap = _snap && _floating;
                      });
                    },
                    value: _floating,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```